# How to inflate a textview xml in my layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a custom textview class and i am trying to inflate it in my main xml. Here is my code :-

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView{

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    TextView view = (TextView) li.inflate(R.layout.customtextview,null);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

}

customtextview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="sgfiughbjkh"
    android:id="@+id/customtext"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</TextView>
```

and in my main activity xml, i have only one linear layout :-

```
    LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
    CustomTextView cus = new CustomTextView(this);
    main.addView(cus);
```

I know if i extend it to linear layout instead of textview and add a lienarlayout as parent and in it that textview, it works.

But the problem is that i want to inflate an xml with only a textview and inflate it and the above code is not working.
Please suggest

How do inflate a xml containing only one textview using layout inflator ?

Comment: is your code throws any exception when you inflates view.

Answer (score 6):

```
// inflate text view
    TextView textView =  (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtextview, null);

// add it to your view
// in your condition, we will add it to Linear Layout
  LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
  main.addView(textView);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's old and 2 years later, I ran into the same issue.

You cannot extend from a View and inflate from a layout. The view needs to be wrapped by a ViewGroup . Read [Understanding Android's LayoutInflater.inflate()](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/)

I came up with 2 solutions , either :

**1.** in your class CustomTextView , you set programmatically all the properties . Don't inflate anything. Good luck with conversion from resources `dimen.xml`

**2.** In your Activity , inflate the Textview

```
LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
TextView textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customtextview, null);
// you might need as well to set the layout params again
// LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
// textView.setLayoutParams(params);

main.addView(textView);
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but maybe it will help people.

first and like Pratik goyal said you need to declare your CustomTextView and not a TextView

```
<com.example.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/customTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then in your CustomTextView class you need to had those lines (Constructor):

```
public FontFitTextView(final Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public FontFitTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}
```

And last (correct me if i'm wrong people), but you can't inflate a customView into a TextView.

<strike>TextView textView =  (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtextview, null);</strike>

rather you need to put your R.layout.customTextView into a customTextView

```
CustomTextView customTxtView = (CustomTextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);
```

And now that i'm writing this down i don't think it's possible to inflate only a TextView. If you want to inflate R.layout.customlayout you need to have at least a layout (Linear,Relative etc...) that wrap your customTextView

Something like this

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.yourpakagename.CustomTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="13" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all of your custom created views under heading **"Custom & Library Views"** in the Graphical interface of Eclipse.

If your CustomTextView is in the package "com.example" than you can define your custom component as :

```
<com.example.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/customTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Actually, like we create a linear layout class and inflate a view in it, can we do the same for a textview only xml like the xml contains only one textview.Can we extend a class with textview and inflate it